# Problem with YAML when compiling Camera_Calibration_Parsers

Tags: robotic-arm, build-from-source, odroid, yaml-cpp, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently having a problem with compiling Camera_Calibration_Parsers ([error](http://pastebin.com/gJk3vtA2)) for Groovy.  I am working with an ARM processor and building from source.  There isn't a libyaml-cpp-dev or yaml-cpp-dev binary available from apt-get so I am attempting an install from source.  I have tried many ways on my own as well as trying to follow [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/36319/how-to-install-yaml-cpp026-dev-how-to-install-from-source-correctly/).

I have also confirmed having the share libraries option selected for CMake.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64101/problem-with-yaml-when-compiling-camera_calibration_parsers/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution I found was a combination of installing yaml-cpp-0.3.0 from source (which I already did) and removing the pre-built components of camera_calibration_parser (which I did not).

First, when installing yaml-cpp-0.3.0, make sure you open the configuration of the CMake file (i.e. run "ccmake .." in the build directory).  Turn the option "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS" ON.

Second, navigate to the "build_isolated" folder under ros/groovy.  Remove the camera_calibration_parser folder.  Then you are safe to rebuild it.

As a note, the error was not only related to the "GetType" function.  There were other times that different functions in yaml-cpp caused the error.

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this problem.

---

Originally posted by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) with karma: 213 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndrewLawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/11631/andrewlawson/) on 2014-03-10**:
Thanks so much, I was struggling with this issue and didn't think to remove the pre-built components!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check what version of yaml-cpp is installed in your system. If it's 0.5.0 you will have troubles compiling camera_calibration_paser. Try to downgrade to  yaml-cpp to 0.3.0.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-06-01**:
There is a binary of yaml-cpp that is installable and does so when I try to apt-get camera_calibration_parser.  It is 0.2.7.  I have tried to install 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.3.0, and 0.5.0 with no luck.  In the process I did make sure to uninstall the apt-get version.  There are no -dev versions.

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-06-03**:
Thanks for the help. Finally figured out what my simple issue was.